# What crimes can you get away with as thane?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just became thane in Whiterun and was wondering, What crimes can you get away with as thane, and how many times can you use your rank as an excuse for crime?

Comment: I'd say exact duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

The thane title can allow you to get away with a murder once and numerous smaller crimes. If your bounty is really low, like from a single lockpicking, just say "Do you really have time for this?" No reason to use the Thane option. Also:

> guards will forgive your bounty up to 1999 gold (once per hold).

Source:  [Thane](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thane) and [Crime](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Crime) articles at UESP

Comment: If you're going to copy-paste things like "[Guards will forgive your bounty up to 1999 gold (once per hold).](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thane)" you really need to cite your source. Not doing so is plagiarism, and in this case is additionally a violation of the copyright license of the UESP wiki.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Then why don't you edit it? I have looked into this and the content falls under "Attribution-ShareAlike 2.5 License" which means you need to name the writer of the specific text, even if you alter the quote. But where can we find the original author of it? I cannot find him/her.

Comment: I cant find an owner so the content must belong to the site creator Dave Humphrey. I'm still not sure so i won't edit the original answer.

Comment: @MennoGouw According to the [Attribution-ShareAlike 2.5 Generic](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) license page, "*You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor*". And according to the [UESPWiki: Copyright and Ownership](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/UESPWiki:Copyright_and_Ownership) page, "*The copyright of a particular edit is owned by the user who made the edit*" and "*You must give attribution to the article from which the content was taken*".

Comment: And StackExchange has very strict policies about attribution.  Not providing attribution is plagiarism, and we delete that.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Skyrim Wiki" (there are, in fact, at least two wikis containing extensive information about the ES series). Please provide an *exact link* to the site you took the information from.

Comment: I gave you the link. That's all you need for attribution. Just never, never copy-paste your answers as if you wrote the words. It's your job to cite your sources and use quote formatting. It's not our job to follow everyone around to make sure they're not plagiarising. (It's not *our* accounts in danger of banning.) I'll show you how it's done so you can do it next time.

Comment: There. Please look it over and make sure the rest of the words are either your own original work or are put in quote marks or use a blockquote.